# What is the easiest way to change key in scala map?

Tags: scala, dictionary, collections

I have a `mutable.Map` which I need to change a key of if the key is present. If not I want to add a new mapping. Here is what I mean:

```
val m = mutable.HashMap[String, String]()
val default = "default"
val key = "key_to_change"
val newKey = "key_to_set"
if(m.contains(key)) {
    val oldValue = m(key)
    m remove key
    m += newKey -> oldValue
} else m += newKey -> default
```

I wonder if scala does not have a more concise way to perform such "key-changing". Can you suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`remove` ["removes a key from this map, returning the value associated previously with that key as an option"](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Map.html#remove(key:K):Option[V]), so

```
val value = m.remove(key).getOrElse(default)
m += newKey -> value
```